Parallel transport along great circles in $S^n$
I would like to calculate the parallel transport map along great circles in $S^n$. I was not able to find any reference for this online (except for maybe $S^2$).
To be more precise, let $\nabla$ be the usual connection on $S^n$ inherited from the dot product in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. Let $\gamma$ be a path in $S^n$. A vector field $V$ along $\gamma$ is said to be parallel if $D_tV=\nabla_{\gamma'}V\equiv0$. Here, ''a vector field $V$ along $\gamma$'' means a section of the pullback bundle $\gamma^*(TS^n)$, and the symbol $D_tV=\nabla_{\gamma'}V$ denotes the pullback connection. More details can be found on page 102 of Lee's Introduction to Riemannian Manifolds.
Now, given any great circle $\gamma$, we can always choose an orthogonal transformation $A$ which take $\gamma$ to the equator. Without loss of generality, assume that $\gamma(t)=(\cos t,\sin t,0,\ldots,0)$, and $\gamma$ starts at $t=0$. Then given any $v=(v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_{n+1})$ perpendicular to $\gamma(0)=(1,0,0,\ldots,0)$, we have $v_1=0$. I suspect that the vector field $V(t)=(-v_2\sin t,v_2\cos t,v_3,\ldots,v_{n+1})$ is parallel along $\gamma$, so $V(t)$ is the parallel transport of $V(0)=v$ along $\gamma$. Is this correct at all? If so, how do I prove this rigorously?
Any help would be appreciated!

Parallel transport is unique. Note that if you start with a vector $w$ orthogonal to the plane of the geodesic, the “constant” vector field $w$ is parallel along the geodesic. Understanding $S^2$ thoroughly is going to get you farther than you think.

@TedShifrin So, in general, do I just break down a vector $w$ into two components, one orthogonal to the geodesic plane, and one along the direction of the geodesic? The first component is kept the same, and the second just changes according to the velocity of the geodesic?

A geodesic has constant speed, of course. So what precisely happens to the tangential component?

@TedShifrin The tangential component just moves along the geodesic? Is there any ambiguity here?

That is far from a precise mathematical statement, but I suspect you know the answer.

To amplify Ted's first comment, understanding parallel transport along a circle (the one-sphere) tells you parallel transport along a great circle of the $n$-sphere: Decompose the tangent bundle of the ambient space along your great circle into (i) The tangent direction to the circle, (ii) The normal direction to the circle in the plane of the circle (which is not tangent to the $n$-sphere), and (iii) the $(n-1)$-dimensional orthogonal complement of the plane of the great circle. <> Please feel free to write up the details yourself!

@TedShifrin Could you explain why "if $w$ is orthogonal to the plane of the geodesic, the “constant” vector field $w$ is parallel along the geodesic"? I wanted to use the definition of pullback connection but things seem to be a little cumbersome if I do it that way.

Don’t be so fancy. A constant vector field is parallel along a path if and only if it is tangent to the submanifold at each point.
